# Creating a string from a lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have functions that take SQL where clauses, and I'm wondering if there's a way to make them all strongly typed.  Is there a way to take a lambda expression like a => a.AgencyID == id and convert it to a string where clause?  Like "AgencyID = 'idValue'"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn the lambda function into an [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/charlie/expression-tree-basics), and then traverse the tree to build your string.