# Is there a 3rd party library that knows to convert a linq expression to a human readable string representation?

Tags: .net, linq, lambda, expression-trees, human-readable

I have a linq expression and I wish to display it in the log in a human readable form. Any one knows any library that can do it? I saw this entry [Creating a string from a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294438/creating-a-string-from-a-lambda-expression), but it is not that useful, in my opinion.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Now that I think about it, my case is probably not that representative, because my linq expression includes a type name inside, which is expanded by the ToString to something totally monstrous, because the type is a generic one. For example, the expression `e => e.TypeName == typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName` where T is my generic context is expanded to:

```
"e => (e.TypeName == \"Shunra.Infra.DummyEntity.Contract.IDummyEntity`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Shunra.Infra.DummyEntity.Contract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=807fc02bc4ce69db\")"
```

Looks like demanding that the assembly qualified name be nicely formatted is not fair at all...

Comment: if you are looking for something you can just use off the shelf, that link won't be helpful to you.  Since I don't think something already exists that you want, however, you should take a closer look at that link.  If you know how to traverse expression trees, you can easily build a string that describes the content however you want.   However, what is wrong with how the expressions render with just .ToString()?  Can you post the code to your LINQ expression?

Comment: I know to traverse linq expression. But it is at least a day of work and if I can save it - my win.

Comment: sure, I understand.  Still, can you post your LINQ code, and also a sample of what kind of "human readable" output you're hoping for?

Comment: @Kirk, my mistake. Looks like my demands are unreasonable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `ToString`, the output is fairly readable, at least to a programmer...